# Does Tensorflow.unstack() Remove or Rearrange data?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been trying to understand how Tensorflow.Unstack() works. I've read the documentation a few times here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unstack

According to the Tensorflow documentation "the dimension unpacked along is gone". It sounds like unstacking a tensor removes data from the original tensor. Is this true? Or does it only rearrange the data?

In my code example, in Y, it appears that it has removed the fourth row of X. What confuses me, is why does it leave the row on the side of matrix? Is the function actually removing the row or leaving it there? I'm not quite sure what to make of the output.

```
import tensorflow as tf

X = tf.constant(np.array(range(24)).reshape(2, 3, 4))

Y = tf.unstack(X, axis=0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print("X ", sess.run(X))
    print("Y ", sess.run(Y))


#Ouput
X [[[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]]

 [[12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23]]]

Y [array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
          [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
          [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]), array([[12, 13, 14, 15],
          [16, 17, 18, 19],
          [20, 21, 22, 23]])]
```

Comment: if i have answered your question. Kindly accept answer and up vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we perform unstack on tensor it wont remove the data but it will rearrange it.

Syntax for tf.unstack as below:

```
tf.unstack(
    value, num=None, axis=0, name='unstack'
)
```

Unstack: split the `value`(i.e. input) according to the specified `axis`, and output the list containing `num` elements.

Here X.shape is (2,3,4),

If axis=0, `num` must be filled with 2. After transformation, the list (i.e. output) has 2 elements, and the shape of the element is (3,4).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

print("Tensorflow Version:",tf.__version__)

X = tf.constant(np.array(range(24)).reshape(2, 3, 4))

Y = tf.unstack(X, axis=0) 

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print("\n")
    print("Shape:", X)
    print("\n")
    print("X ", sess.run(X))
    print("\n")
    print("Shape:",Y)
    print("\n")
    print("Y ", sess.run(Y))
```

Output:

```
Tensorflow Version: 1.15.0


Shape: Tensor("Const_1:0", shape=(2, 3, 4), dtype=int64)


X  [[[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]]

 [[12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23]]]


Shape: [<tf.Tensor 'unstack_1:0' shape=(3, 4) dtype=int64>, <tf.Tensor 'unstack_1:1' shape=(3, 4) dtype=int64>]


Y  [array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]), array([[12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])]
```